# Entity Data source wizard version is only compatible with Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

I am using visual studio 2017 with Microsoft .NET framework version 4.7 and Entity Framework 6 and SQL Server 2012.

while adding Data source to a Web Form:

[image]

I have this error:

[image]

I did add **Dynamic Data provider for Entity Framework 6 & EntityDataSource control for Entity Framework 6**
as a solution proposed on the same question but it didn't work for me and I still have the same problem.

Is there any solution (without the downgrading to Entity Framework 5) ?

And Thanks